# QGIS Filter layer by expression

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, select-by-attribute, filter

In PyQGIS, I am having difficulty using a filter expression on a feature layer.

```
for feature in iter:
    name_dot =  feature['name']
print name_dot
expr = QgsExpression("\"name\"=name_dot")
selection= layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))    
ids = [s.id() for s in selection]
layer.setSelectedFeatures(ids)
iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
```

This does not work, and I do not know where the mistake is.

Answer (score 6):

Presuming `iter` is something like `iter=iface.activeLayer.getFeatures()`, behind the loop `name_dot` contains the name of the last feature returned by the feature iterator.

This must be passed to the QgsExpression via string formatting like

```
 expr = QgsExpression('"name"=\'%s\'' % name_dot)
```

(Field names in double quotes, string in single quotes)

Here is a screenshot visualizing the steps (cp. the python console):

[image]

**UPDATE**

Fading out all the features not matching the expression works via *subset strings* (aka *definitinon queries*) `layer` is your selected layer:

```
layer.setSubsetString('"name"=\'%s\'' % name_dot)
```

(Note that this is the same expression as above, and that is not necessary to select something before applying the `subsetString`)

You can verify this in the layer properties (right click layer > properties):

[image]

You can undo this by simply setting the `subsetString` to an empty string like:

```
layer.setSubsetString('')
```

Comment: thank you so much. and one more question: how can I hide the layer and show only the object, which was found out after the filtering? (Qgis 2.8)

Comment: I'll update the answer...

Comment: thanks, 
#root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
#node = root.findLayer(iface.activeLayer().id())
#node.setVisible(False) - my try
but i can not understand, how to make only one object visible

Comment: but doesn't this set the whole layer invisible, not only the features not matching your expression?

Comment: I have a layer consisting of the points. filter I highlight one point. and I need it to only one displayed on the screen. How can I do that?

Comment: tried the steps above?

Comment: yes, and it helps, thanks! but i want not to zoom a dot. but make all dots invisible, except one, that i get from filtering

Comment: root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
node = root.findLayer(iface.activeLayer().id())
node.setVisible(False) - it helps me to hide all dots. BUT now i want to show filtred dots only on my screen. how can i do this?

Comment: Do the following steps (don't set the layer invisible): 1) Zoom to the whole layer, 2) apply the subsetString and then 3) do your selection (WITHOUT zooming to the result). Then you should have your layer extent with only the highlighted dot displayed. Hint: When you zoom to the whole layer AFTER applying the subsetString, only the features matching the expression are taken into account (qgis then behaves like all other pointy don't exist), that's why it zooms to only one (the selected) point.

Comment: My God, I'm so stupid! many thanks! I love you, man

Comment: Hey, noone using qgis is stupid :-) just consider voting and accepting the answer, and welcome to GIS.SE by the way ;-)

Comment: Oh, thanks one more time. Сould you, please, advise me a good book or tutorial of python on QGIS

Comment: Yap, you could buy this https://locatepress.com/ppg or take a look in the official doku (QGIS developer cookbook) under http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/ (also available in various languages, e.g. russian: http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/pdf/ru/ where you can even find a tutorial. The translation might not necissarily be complete, perhaps you can help translate it). The 2.14 Doku is on the way with the next LTR, I think. Watch out... And A.Graser holds an UNIGIS module on QGIS (http://www.unigis.at/index.php/qgis-an-open-source-desktop-gis , chargeable for non-students).

Comment: Could we use a layout instead of map? I need layers of a fixed size and scale for export to the picture (.png). and on this  "background" points should be displayed one by one.

Comment: For shure. But this broadness goes far beyond the intention of SE. I think these layout features are well enough documented, so that I'm shure that you can make it on your own with a small amount of study. If you are struggeling with special issues in this do not hesitate to ask for these.