# Keeping virtual layer up to date

Tags: qgis, csv, qgis-2, virtual-layer

I have a virtual layer in QGIS 2 with a query on a CSV. The CSV gets updated regulary. I need the max/min attributes in the virtual layer to be updated as well. The virtual layer is used as a title in print composer (displayed as attribute table).

The query looks like `SELECT "Events between " as from, min(fromdate) as fromdate, " and " as to, max(todate) as todate from "Events_Happening" WHERE invalid = 0`
(Events_Happening is the .csv)

How can I achieve this without recreating the virtual layer by hand every time the csv is updated? (Update on QGIS startup would be enough)

Comment: In QGIS 3 it should update on every canvas refresh by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably create a **macro** so that when you open your project, your query can be run immediately. You can create one from the toolbar:

```
Project > Project Properties > Macros
```

Then use something like:

```
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry
from qgis.utils import iface

def openProject():
    name = 'virtual_layer'
    query = 'SELECT "Events between " as from, min(fromdate) as fromdate, " and " as to, max(todate) as todate from "Events_Happening" WHERE invalid = 0'
    vLayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(name)[0]
    vLayer.setDataSource("?query={}".format(query), vLayer.name(), "virtual")
    vLayer.triggerRepaint()

def saveProject():
    pass

def closeProject():
    pass
```

[image: Macro]

Make sure to **save** your project. Now the next time you load your project (you don't need to restart QGIS), it should hopefully update the virtual layer.

Answer (score 5):

This method uses a bit of python and the QGIS project openProject() method:

1. Open blank QGIS and select Project (menu)>Project Properties>Macros tab and enable macro
2. Under the openProject() method, create a csv virtual layer ([see](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html)):

   uri = "/some/path/file.csv?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (";", "x", "y")

   vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "layer name you like", "delimitedtext")
3. Add vector layer to canvas:

   QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
4. Set sql subset expression using setSubsetString() method, see [QGIS Filter layer by expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200017/qgis-filter-layer-by-expression)
5. Finally save project file (you may also need to enable macros within the QGIS Settings>Options section)

Each time you open this project it should re-create the csv virtual layer and apply the sql filter.

Comment: Pretty much the same train of thought :)